# Are comments disabled (today)?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I went to a few different places in the forum and it appears I wasn't able to comment or vote.  Is this a feature-- if it's because of Christmas, I find it an interesting and perhaps useful gesture.  Otherwise, is this a bug (I'm using Chrome?).

Comment: You were logged in?

Comment: On a Win7 box w/ Chrome, perhaps grossly overdue for a reboot, I could not add comments, open inbox, or rate questions, but I could create new ones.

On MacBook Pro, everything's cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me. Try a full reload, sometimes if your JavaScript backend stuff gets cached it won't talk to the servers right.

Usually when the SE team does anything that affects the functionality of the site they will throw it into read only mode and a banner on top of the site will let you know that you cannot do anything but read. I haven't seen such such thing today and the fact that you could post this question contradicts this anyway.